# Why am i getting this error "name is not defined" when it is?

Tags: python

Why am i getting this error? The picture has the details. I need to get the _spent values to print the proper amount of times. So, say it runs through the loop 3 times, I need it to print 3. I think that is where the 1s are coming from. I don't like it! [image]

```
pennies = 10
nickels = 10
dimes = 10
quarters = 10

print("\nWelcome to change-making program.")
in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

while in_str.lower() != 'q':
    dollar_str, cents_str = in_str.split(".")

    if in_str.lower() == 'q':
        quit()

    in_int = int(float(in_str) * 100)

    if in_int < 0:
        print("Error: purchase price must be non-negative.")
        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

    if in_int > 0:
        payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
        payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)
        change = payment_int - in_int

        #determines if there payment input
        if payment_int < in_int:
            print("Error: Insufficient payment.")
            payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
            payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)


        if change == 0:
            print("No change.")

        #determines how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies are left
        while change >= 25 and quarters > 0:
            change = change - 25
            quarters_spent = 0
            quarters_spent += 1
            quarters = quarters - quarters_spent
        print(quarters_spent)

        while change >= 10 and dimes > 0:
            change = change - 10
            dimes_spent = 0
            dimes_spent += 1
            dimes = dimes - dimes_spent
        print(dimes_spent)

        while change >= 5 and nickels > 0:
            change = change - 5
            nickels_spent = 0
            nickels_spent += 1
            nickels = nickels - nickels_spent
        print(nickels_spent)

        while change >= 1 and pennies > 0:
            change = change - 1
            pennies_spent = 0
            pennies_spent += 1
            pennies = pennies - pennies_spent

        if quarters == 0 and dimes == 0 and nickels == 0 and pennies == 0:
            print("Error: ran out of coins.")
            quit()

        print("\nCollect Payment Below:")
        print(10 - quarters, "Quarters")

        print("\nStock: ", quarters, "Quarters, ", dimes, " Dimes, ", nickels, " Nickels, ", pennies, " Pennies ")

        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

        pennies = pennies
        nickels = nickels
        dimes = dimes
        quarters = quarters
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening in the code?

Comment: Oh, i guess the picture didnt upload. My b. It says that "nickels_spent" is undefined even though it is. it will do this with the other variables ending in "_spent" so i think it has something to do with my if statements but i dont know what exactly

Comment: But where in the code. The picture says line 70, but I can't tell where that is I this snippet.

Comment: Because the indentation of `print` is not correct , it's not in `while` so outside of `while` scope `nickels_score` is not defined.

Comment: @user7433120 Oh whoops, it's on the print line. Missed that.

Comment: yeah, i tried that. It prints out the quarters correctly, however it doesnt print out anything else. line 70 is print(nickels_spent)

Comment: I think you need to change `change = payment_int - in_int` to `change = in_int - payment_int` to get a positive change value

Comment: @Arman `while` does not have its own scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only defined and initialized this variable `nickels_spent` inside the while loop

However, if the condition is not met, the program will skip the loop and jump to execute this `print(nickels_spent)` statement where this variable is not yet defined.

You can either

1. Move the print statement into the while loop

Or

2. Define and initialize this variable outside the while loop.

Depends on the purpose of your program

Comment: I did what Arman said and i moved the statements inside of the while loops. However, now only the first while loops results get printed, usually print(quarters_spent) is only printed. Ill try initializing them outside of the loop

Comment: That is probably because the conditions fails and the program did not go into that loop, if it is not what you are looking for, pls revise your logic, and pls upvote if u feel the answer is useful

Answer (score 1):

This error implies that you didn't define the value `nickels_spent` before trying to use it.

I guess the error is in this line: `print (nickels_spent)`.

What is probably happening is that the `while` statement condition that is used to assign a value to that variable is not true when you try to run it, so it wasn't defined but you still try to use it.

Try debugging before that `while` loop to see what exactly happens there.